# Prevent opening a link in new tab if the url has already opened in a tab

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

I have some links in the menu bar. I want if the user clicks on a link for example "http://example.com/Archive" and when this link is opened in a tab if user clicks again on that link again the browser focus on the previous opened tab.
How can I do it with javascript? 
*the solution must support old Internet explorers too.

Answer (score 1):

Give every link a unique `target`.

`<a href="http://example.com/Archive" target="uniqueTarget">somelink</a>`

Or

`window.open('http://example.com/Archive','uniqueTarget')`

Answer (score 1):

for Internet Explorer, You can try to work with Window instead of tab. Because we cannot get tab id in IE.

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">click here...</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "demo", "width=200,height=100");
  myWindow.document.write("<p>A new window!</p>");
  myWindow.focus();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```